# Erro ao passar parâmetros numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop signature matching types (dtype('&lt;U21')

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, parâmetros, numpy

Basicamente eu tenho o seguinte código:

```py
import numpy as np

def localize(aux1, aux2, aux3, aux4, aux5, aux6):

    search = np.array([(aux1,aux2,aux3,aux4,aux5,aux6)])

    B1A = np.array([(-46,-78,-72,-70,-81,-59)])     #B1A
    B1B = np.array([(-100,-82,-85,-100,-76,-55)])   #B1B
    B1C = np.array([(-100,-100,-100,-78,-100,-58)]) #B1C
    B2A = np.array([(-100,-88,-100,-100,-100,-60)])  #B2A
    B2B = np.array([(-100,-78,-79,-80,-80,-59)])     #B2B

    candidatos = [B1A, B1B, B1C, B2A, B2B]
    margem_erroP = 10.0
    margem_erroN = -10.0

    distancias = candidatos[::] - search

    avaliar_dist = np.where(np.absolute(distancias) < margem_erroP, True, False) 
    avaliar_distN = np.where(np.absolute(distancias) < margem_erroN, True, False)

    vetores_aprovados = avaliar_dist.all(axis=2)
    vetores_aprovados += avaliar_distN.all(axis=2)

    posicao_aprovados = np.array(np.where(vetores_aprovados== True)[0])

    print("---- Resultado ----")
    print()
    print("Busca: {}".format(search))
    print("Resultado: ")
    for x in posicao_aprovados:
        print(candidatos[x])

        here = candidatos[x][-1]
        print("Aquii")
        print(here)

        if posicao_aprovados[0] == 0:
            print("Local: B1A")
            local = "B1A"
        elif posicao_aprovados[0] == 1:
            print("Local: B1B")
            local = "B1B"
        elif posicao_aprovados[0] == 2:
            print("Local: B1C")
            local = "B1C"
        elif posicao_aprovados[0] == 3:
            print("Local: B2A")
            local = "B2A"
        elif posicao_aprovados[0] == 4:
            print("Local: B2B")
            local = "B2B"
        else:
            local = "não encontrado"

    x = {
        "search" : search.tolist(),
        "locale" : local,
        "result" : here.tolist()
    }
    json.dumps(x)
    return x
```

> Até aí tudo bem, funciona certinho conforme preciso!

O problema está quando tento executar esta função de outro local. Por exemplo:

Tenho uma variável **find** que contém a seguinte string: `'-100,-67,-63,-49,-53,-48'`

Como preciso passar 6 valores e nesse caso estou passando só 1 (uma string) eu separo minha string em números inteiros utilizando o seguinte comando:
`valores = find.split(",")`

Feito isso agora minha lista se torna isso: `['-100', '-67', '-63', '-49', '-53', '-48']`

Para fazer minha função rodar eu fiz da seguinte forma: `aux = localize.localize(valores[0],valores[1],valores[2],valores[3],valores[4],valores[5])`

Passando dessa forma o que eu estou fazendo é basicamente: `localize.localize(-100 -67 -63 -49 -53 -48)`

Porém não funciona retornando o erro:
`distancias = candidatos[::] - search numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U21'), dtype('<U21')) -> dtype('<U21')`

**IMPORTANTE MENCIONAR QUE**
Se eu chamar minha função passando diretamente os valores dessa forma: `aux = localize.localize(-100,-70,-68,-55,-53,-55)`
Funciona perfeitamente mas passando dessa outra forma que é como preciso não vai de jeito nenhum.

Cheguei a achar que ele não estava funcionando porque não tinha nenhuma vírgula separando cada valor inteiro então fiz da seguinte forma: `localize.localize(valores[0]+',',valores[1]+',',valores[2]+',',valores[3]+',',valores[4]+',',valores[5])`

Que era o mesmo que passar:

`localize.localize(-100,-67,-63,-49,-53,-48)` o qual também não funcionou.

**Gostaria de ajuda para entender como posso passar os valores de forma que seja funcional e por meio das variáveis conforme descrevi. Agradeço desde já qualquer ajuda**

Caso ajude deixo abaixo a função da qual estou tentando executar. Ela é um POST de uma API que vem com alguns parâmetros (coordenadas) e o algoritmo vai me ajudar a dizer qual é o local que essas coordenadas estão mais próximas. Só então depois de receber os dados e verificar qual o local está que são salvos os dados no banco. Eu estava printando tudo para ver como estavam vindo os dados hehe

```py
@app.route('/api/v1/resources/positions/app', methods=['POST'])
def positions_post_app():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('locale.db')
    conn.row_factory = dict_factory
    cur = conn.cursor()
    users = request.get_json()
    for user in users:
        user_id = user['user_id']
        find = user['search']
        date = user['date']

#        print("valor que chega!")
#        print(find)
#        valores = find.split(",")
#        print("lista de inteiros")
#        print(valores)
#        print("Tabela atualizada:")
#        print(valores[0]+',',valores[1]+',',valores[2]+',',valores[3]+',',valores[4]+',',valores[5])

#        aux = localize.localize(-100,-70,-68,-55,-53,-55) #FUNÇÃO FUNCIONANDO
         aux = localize.localize(valores[0],valores[1],valores[2],valores[3],valores[4],valores[5])

        locale = aux['locale']
        result = aux['result']
        print("insert into positions values(NULL, '{}','{}', {}, {}, '{}')".format(user_id, find, result, locale, date)) #PRINT PARA VER COMO FICARIA O SQL 

#        cur.execute("insert into positions values(NULL, '{}','{}', {}, {}, '{}')".format(user_id, search, result, locale, date))
#        conn.commit()
    return {'Status' : 'Success'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeira coisa que vamos fazer é replicar o seu erro.

```
import numpy as np

def localize(aux1, aux2, aux3, aux4, aux5, aux6):

    search = np.array([(aux1,aux2,aux3,aux4,aux5,aux6)])

    B1A = np.array([(-46,-78,-72,-70,-81,-59)])     #B1A
    B1B = np.array([(-100,-82,-85,-100,-76,-55)])   #B1B
    B1C = np.array([(-100,-100,-100,-78,-100,-58)]) #B1C
    B2A = np.array([(-100,-88,-100,-100,-100,-60)])  #B2A
    B2B = np.array([(-100,-78,-79,-80,-80,-59)])     #B2B

    candidatos = [B1A, B1B, B1C, B2A, B2B]


    return candidatos[::] - search #Aqui acontece o erro

find = '-100,-67,-63,-49,-53,-48'

valores = find.split(",")

print(valores)

print(localize(valores[0],valores[1],valores[2],valores[3],valores[4],valores[5]))
```

retornando:

```
['-100', '-67', '-63', '-49', '-53', '-48']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 24, in <module>    print(localize(valores[0],valores[1],valores[2],valores[3],valores[4],valores[5]))
  File "main.py", line 16, in localize    return candidatos[::] - searchnumpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: 
  ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U21'), dtype('<U21')) -> dtype('<U21')
```

O que foi feito?

Foi feita a simplificação a função `localize()` deixando apenas a porção relacionada com a mensagem de erro.
A réplica a maneira como obteve os valores a serem passados como parâmetros para `localize()` e a impressão da lista `valores`:

```
['-100', '-67', '-63', '-49', '-53', '-48']
```

Como pode verificar `valores` é lista de strings e quando faz:

```
return candidatos[::] - search
```

Obtém o erro na operação pois os elemento das matrizes `candidatos` e `search` são de tipos diferentes e operador `-` não consegue aplicar a função [`numpy.subtract()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.subtract.html) entre inteiros e strings.

Para corrigir esse problema basta assegurar que ao criar a matriz `search` essa matriz será uma matriz de inteiros. Para fazer isso no constructor [`numpy.array()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html), determine o tipo de dado da matriz resultante ajustando o parâmetro `dtype` como [`np.int_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html):

```
search = np.array([(aux1,aux2,aux3,aux4,aux5,aux6)], dtype=np.int_)
```

No exemplo simplificado:

```
import numpy as np

def localize(aux1, aux2, aux3, aux4, aux5, aux6):

    search = np.array([(aux1,aux2,aux3,aux4,aux5,aux6)], dtype=np.int_) #Agora cria uma matriz de inteiros

    B1A = np.array([(-46,-78,-72,-70,-81,-59)])     #B1A
    B1B = np.array([(-100,-82,-85,-100,-76,-55)])   #B1B
    B1C = np.array([(-100,-100,-100,-78,-100,-58)]) #B1C
    B2A = np.array([(-100,-88,-100,-100,-100,-60)])  #B2A
    B2B = np.array([(-100,-78,-79,-80,-80,-59)])     #B2B

    candidatos = [B1A, B1B, B1C, B2A, B2B]


    return candidatos[::] - search 

find = '-100,-67,-63,-49,-53,-48'

valores = find.split(",")

print(valores)

#Agora funciona com parâmetros string
print(localize(valores[0],valores[1],valores[2],valores[3],valores[4],valores[5]))

#Continua funcionando com parâmetros inteiros
print(localize(-100,-67,-63,-49,-53,-48))
```

Retornando:

```
['-100', '-67', '-63', '-49', '-53', '-48']
[[[ 54 -11  -9 -21 -28 -11]]
 [[  0 -15 -22 -51 -23  -7]]
 [[  0 -33 -37 -29 -47 -10]] 
 [[  0 -21 -37 -51 -47 -12]] 
 [[  0 -11 -16 -31 -27 -11]]]
[[[ 54 -11  -9 -21 -28 -11]]    
 [[  0 -15 -22 -51 -23  -7]]    
 [[  0 -33 -37 -29 -47 -10]]    
 [[  0 -21 -37 -51 -47 -12]]    
 [[  0 -11 -16 -31 -27 -11]]]
```

Exemplo simplificado funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/AccurateStandardJavascript).

> **OBS**: No caso eu entendi sendo como inteiro o tipo de dado de sua operação caso eu tenha me equivocado e os dados são de ponto flutuante
>   ao invés de usar `dtype=np.int_` use `dtype=np.float`. Para outros
>   tipos de dados consulte [NumPy Data Types](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html) para uma lista dos tipos
>   de dados disponíveis.

Comment: Perfeito Augusto! Era isso mesmo. Eu sabia que por algum motivo mesmo eu mandando números corretos algo a mais precisava pois com o teste com números diretamente deu. Você me salvou bem com essa resposta e muito bem explicado da sua parte!

Sim, são números inteiros mesmo. Eu achei que por ter convertido a minha lista string para lista inteiro já funcionaria no numpy. Muito obrigado mesmo